# How to populate client-side Meteor.user.services after OAuth with built-in accounts-ui package in Meteor v1.4+?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm using *accounts-ui* and *accounts-google* in Meteor v1.4.1. I can't get the `user.services` object to appear scoped in the client code. In particular, I need google's profile picture.

I've configured the server-side code to authenticate with Google like so:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { ServiceConfiguration } from 'meteor/service-configuration';

const services = Meteor.settings.private.oauth;
for (let service of Object.keys(services)) {
  ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert({
    service
  }, {
    $set: {
      clientId: services[service].app_id,
      secret: services[service].secret,
      loginStyle: "popup"
    }
  });
}
```

...and the client side code to configure permissions like so:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  requestPermissions: {
    google: ['email', 'profile']
  },
  forceApprovalPrompt: {
    google: true
  },
  passwordSignupFields: 'EMAIL_ONLY'
});
```

When users click the 'Sign-In with Google' button, a pop-up appears and they can authenticate. No prompt appears, however, despite `forceApprovalPrompt` being set to true for `google`.

The big issue is that when I execute this,

```
const user = Meteor.user();
console.log(user.services);
```

anywhere in client code, I do not see the expected user services information. I check my database and it is definitely there for the taking:

```
$ mongo localhost:27017
> db.users.find({})
> ... "services" : { "google" : { "accessToken" : ... } } ...
```

I'm curious what I'm missing? Should I explicitly define a *publish* function in order for user services data to exist in the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The services property is intentionally hidden on the client side for security reasons. There are a couple of approaches here :

**Suggestions**

1. My preferred one would be to expose a meteor method to bring you the
   public keys and avatars you might need in the few places you'd need
   them.
2. On a successful login, you could record the data you need somewhere in the user object, but outside of the services property.
3. As you said, you could make a new publication which explicitly specifies which fields to retrieve and which ones to hide. You have to be careful what you publish, though.

**Code Examples**

1. Meteor methods:

```js
// server
Meteor.methods({
    getProfilePicture() {
        const services = Meteor.user().services;
        // replace with actual profile picture property
        return services.google && services.google.profilePicture;
    }
});

// client
Meteor.call('getProfilePicture', (err, profilePicture) => {
    console.log('profile picture url', profilePicture);
});
```

2. Update on successful user creation (you might want to have a login hook as well to reflect any avatar/picture changes in google):

```js
// Configure what happens with profile data on user creation
Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
  if (!('profile' in options)) { options.profile = {}; }
  if (!('providers' in options.profile)) { options.profile.providers = {}; }
  // Define additional specific profile options here
  if (user.services.google) {
    options.profile.providers.google = {
      picture: user.services.google.picture
    }
  }
  user.profile = options.profile;
  return user;
});
```

3. Publish only select data...

```js
// Server
Meteor.publish('userData', function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({ _id: this.userId }, {
      fields: { other: 1, things: 1 }
    });
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});
// Client
Meteor.subscribe('userData');
```